# Circular collision in my game slightly larger than the image

Tags: go, geometry, collision, circular-dependency

I'm implementing circular collision in my game made in Go using a simple rendering framework called Pixel.

The collision works fine with *shapes* like a drawn circle

But when I try to use it with an image instead of a rendered shape, it thinks it collides slightly before it reaches the image. The larger the image, the larger the error.

Here is where it collides on the images:

Smaller image:
[image]

Larger image:
[image]

The collision is done like so:

[s being the solar panel, seen in the "smaller image", and p being the player.]

```
math.Pow(math.Pow(s.center.X-p.center.X, 2)+math.Pow(s.center.Y-p.center.Y, 2), 0.5) <= s.size.X
```

The size.X and size.Y of each image is the same since it's a circle

The centers are calculated correctly and this exact line works with shapes [you can see the yellow outline in the first image, that's the shape it works with.]

Am I doing something wrong? Why would there be an error caused by this when the calculation has nothing to do with the image itself?

Here's how the images are rendered, I assume the problem lies with that somehow:

[g being the generator, seen in the 'Larger image'

```
func (g Generator) render(win *pixelgl.Window, imd *imdraw.IMDraw) {
    mat := pixel.IM.
        Moved(g.center)
    g.sprite.Draw(win, mat)
}
```

The shape is drawn based on it's center as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both colliding objects are circles with radii R1 and R2, then collision occurs when

```
math.Pow(math.Pow(s.center.X-p.center.X, 2)+math.Pow(s.center.Y-p.center.Y, 2), 0.5) <= 
 s.radius + p.radius
```

What is `s.size` - image square side? In this case you have to use `size/2` to get radius.
Why do you ignore size/radius of `p`?

These two reasons together might cause described behavour (collision condition fires when center-center distance becomes equal to `s` side size)

Comment: I'll try this out soon

Comment: Works just fine, thanks for the details in your answer